# why am I getting Unexpected token error in React js project?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am getting error due to to some wrong imports I guess. Below is the error:

```
./src/index.js
SyntaxError: E:\REACT_APP\drf_project\src\index.js: Unexpected token (6:21)

  4 | import './index.css';
  5 | import Route from 'react-router-dom';
> 6 | import BrowserRouter as Switch from 'react-router-dom';
    |                      ^
  7 | import App from './App';
  8 | import Header from './components/Header';
  9 | import Footers from './components/Footers';
```

### index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as serviceWorkers from './serviceWorker';
import './index.css';
import Route from 'react-router-dom';
import BrowserRouter as Switch from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footers from './components/Footers';

const routing = (
    <Route>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
        </Switch>
        <Footers />
        </React.StrictMode>
    </Route>
);

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorkers.unregister();
```

Please consider me new user. I have tried some permutation combination, yet didn't work. The very first import was as below:

```
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
```

It was giving me other error, so I tried to import the sub modules individually. Please suggest what could be the right import for the given error.

Thank you,

new error:

```
Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>
invariant
E:/REACT_APP/drf_project/node_modules/tiny-invariant/dist/tiny-invariant.esm.js:10
(anonymous function)
E:/REACT_APP/modules/Route.js:35
  32 | return (
  33 |   <RouterContext.Consumer>
  34 |     {context => {
> 35 |       invariant(context, "You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>");
     | ^  36 | 
  37 |       const location = this.props.location || context.location;
  38 |       const match = this.props.computedMatch
View compiled
▶ 16 stack frames were collapsed.
Module.<anonymous>
E:/REACT_APP/drf_project/src/index.js:24
  21 |     </Route>
  22 | );
  23 | 
> 24 | ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
  25 | serviceWorkers.unregister();
  26 | 
View compiled
```

previous error:

```
×
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
▶ 22 stack frames were collapsed.
Module.<anonymous>
E:/REACT_APP/drf_project/src/index.js:22
  19 |     </Router>
  20 | );
  21 | 
> 22 | ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
  23 | serviceWorkers.unregister();
  24 |
```

Latest error:

```
./src/index.js
SyntaxError: E:\REACT_APP\drf_project\src\index.js: Identifier 'routing' has already been declared (25:13)

  23 | serviceWorkers.unregister();
  24 | 
> 25 | export const routing
     |              ^
  26 |
```

Comment: try `import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";` if you get any error post it here.

Comment: @angelo, I am getting error, updated the original post.

Comment: What error were you getting instead of unexpected token?

Comment: just added the error. plz chck

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

<Router>
        <React.StrictMode>
        <Header />
          <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
        <Footers />
        </React.StrictMode>
      </Router>
```

As per the error you should use `Route` inside the `Router`.
Please let me know for more.

update

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import * as serviceWorkers from './serviceWorker';
    import './index.css';
    import Route from 'react-router-dom';
    import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
    import App from './App';
    import Header from './components/Header';
    import Footers from './components/Footers';
    
    export const Routing(){ return
     (
        <Router>
          <React.StrictMode>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
            </Switch>
            <Footers />
            </React.StrictMode>
        </Router>
    )
}
    
    ReactDOM.render(<Routing/>, document.getElementById('root'));
    serviceWorkers.unregister();
```

Comment: I tried, am still getting errors, updated the latest error stack, plz check.

Comment: Try these
1) change name from routing to Routing.
2)export const Routing.
ideally you should have created an app.js and written this logic in there,and left index.js as it is.
but try my above suggestions first

Comment: followed your suggestion, got some different error. updated original post.

Comment: updated my answer and please share your entire index.js file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227876/discussion-between-codeoflife-and-user3521180).

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that you tried the first time was correct.

```
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
```

The error message that you got on that first attempt was due to something else. I can see why the error message was misleading because it talks about imports.

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

But the "invalid element" was your `routing` component.  It's a problem because it's not actually a component!

First of all, React components **must** have their first letter capitalized.  Otherwise it assumes that it's a built-in DOM element, like `div` or `h1`.

Secondly, React components **must** be either a `class` (which extends `React.Component`) or a `function`.  What you are trying to write here is a function component which doesn't require any props.  It still needs to be a `function`, so we make it a function with no arguments.  This syntax `() =>` is what's called an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as serviceWorkers from './serviceWorker';
import './index.css';
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footers from './components/Footers';

const Routing = () => (
    <Router>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
        </Switch>
        <Footers />
        </React.StrictMode>
    </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```

There's also a typo: you used `Route` for the outside component but you meant to use `Router`.